# Love to get the output of powershell script in a variable to use in a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, variables, syntax

I have the follow "powershell script"

```
Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType = '3'" | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | select -ExpandProperty SUm
```

And i want to use this to make it happen, but my var variable is empty.
I think it's with the " or ' but i'm a newbie and my knowledge isn't that great with scripting.
Can someone help me with this silly thing?

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell -noprofile {Get-WMIObject -Query "SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType = '3'" | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | select -ExpandProperty SUm}`) DO (
SET var=%%F
```

Comment: You need to escape the `^|`.

Comment: @Squashman - That's what I thought too, but there's apparently more than that

Comment: If you're new to scripting, I'd say that embedding a Powershell pipeline into a CMD batch file. Why not do it all in Powershell? At which point (Powershell 7 here), you just have `$size = (Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType = '3'" | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum).Sum` and then you can just refer to that elsewhere in the Powershell script?

Comment: Agree with previous commenter - why batch at all? Why not just use PowerShell for the whole script?

Comment: You can take a look too at  [Windows Command line get disk space in GB](https://superuser.com/questions/896764/windows-command-line-get-disk-space-in-gb?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that a lot of characters in PowerShell do other things in batch, and they interfere with how `for` loops work. Combine that with the extra of layer of string processing that goes into `for /F` loops, and there's a bunch of extra escaping that is needed.

Ultimately, quotes around everything and double-quoting plus escaping inner quotes seems to do the trick.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`powershell -noprofile "Get-WMIObject -Query \""SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType = '3'\"" | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum | select -ExpandProperty Sum"`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)
echo %var%
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! never got it right with the quotes or double quotes.

Comment: Honestly, I just tried a bunch of stuff until it worked.

Comment: is it possible to round the outcome (%var%)

Comment: Round it to what? I assume powershell has some sort of rounding function, but everything I see is about rounding values with decimals and it's a _little weird_ that your sum of all hard drive sizes isn't an integer.

Comment: Thanks, @Aacini. PowerShell is weird about when it needs extra stuff in order to work correctly. I wish Microsoft hadn't crippled it by default so it would just work like a normal scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using another way. I think it's simplier to understand and I hate cmd's `for` syntax

```
:createTempFileLoop
set "MY_TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\my~%RANDOM%~%RANDOM%~%RANDOM%~%RANDOM%~%RANDOM%.cmd"
if exist "%MY_TEMPFILE%" goto :createTempFileLoop

SET MY_SUMSIZE=-1

@REM Variant powershell.exe -Command [IO.File]::WriteAllText('%MY_TEMPFILE%', 'SET MY_SUMSIZE='+(Get-WMIObject -Query 'SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType = ''3''' ^| Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum).SUM, [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII)

powershell.exe -Command 'SET MY_SUMSIZE='+(Get-WMIObject -Query 'SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk WHERE DriveType = ''3''' ^| Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum).SUM > %MY_TEMPFILE%

call %MY_TEMPFILE%
DEL /Q /F %MY_TEMPFILE%
echo Size is %MY_SUMSIZE%
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it does do the same as the solution form @SomethingDark